# How to call a function VB.NET code via C# Web API

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-web-api2

We have a project developed in VB.NET by our end users. Currently business does not want to migrate it to C# or into REST API's. Instead for phase one they want us to call their VB.NET code via our existing ASP.NET C# WEB API (VB.NET methods directly via our API's).

Can someone please suggest the best practices (Any facade/adapter/interface we could develop) to achieve this or point out to some tutorials or examples?

Appreciate in advance.

With Best Regards

Comment: Are you asking, in a very roundabout way, how to abstract the VB.NET layer?

Comment: Your end user code is available through some sort of assembly, could you refer it from your ASP.NET project?

Comment: Thanks Tim & John, We have the entire source code of end user we can use their Dll's. We want to use that code via dll or directly putting them into our solution and access their methods (kind of abstraction or facade) our code is in WEB API + Angular. We want to trigger the VB.NET functions via our API. Thanks Again

Comment: OK, but what is your question exactly? Whether you should abstract or not? Or what? VB.NET is still .NET, so you can just reference the project as you would any other .NET class library, and call its methods directly.

Comment: Thanks John, We wanted to know are there any best practices or its just plain adding their project references to WEB API and calling their methods? And will it be same like calling from any C# console application?

Comment: Since the both are part of the .NET framework, the language they are written in is irrelevant. They are both compiled to the same bytecode. I think you can just add a reference to the VB DLLs (or to the source projects) in your API project, and then use the bits of code you need.